# Livecycle Javascript Change color of Circle Object

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I am having difficulty accessing the circle object to change its color programmatically. I have tried:

`form1.Page1.Subform1.Circle.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color = "1,191,158";`

but that seems to fill the bounding box of the circle object. I want to change the circle itself. I noticed that within the livecycle UI when you change a color it's within the Object tab as opposed to other objects that have the color in the Border tab. Script assist doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is impossible.

This code gives such error:

```
Circle1.fillColor = "255,255,0";
```

> Invalid property set operation; Draw does not have a "fillColor"
>   property

And this (your) code give such error:

```
Circle1.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "0,255,255";
```

> Invalid property extraction operation; DefaultUi does not have the
>   property "border"

But you can create cicrles with the same size, place them on the same place, then fill them with different colors (in LC Designer), then make one of them invisible. And when it is needed just change circles visibility like that:

```
Circle1.presence = "invisible";
Circle2.presence = "visible";
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for checking. Where did you see the errors? In the javascript dialogue in the preview tab or the log?

Comment: To be able to see errors you should activate Console. Do it with such code: console.show() (type it somewhere in initialization event of your form, to show it right after opening the pdf file). And also, you can use console.println("bla-bla-bla"), to write you output logs to the same console. Note, that after first start of Adobe Reader, Console is shown not immediately, so, it is even faster to open pdf form, them close it (without closing Adobe Reader) and then open it again. Don't know why, but often it works much faster.